# What is different between link,checksums,and signature in maven site

Tags: java, maven

I am new to maven and I want to download maven so I visited [maven Apache official site](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and go to download section but find more links for downloads like
**Link  Checksum    Signature** . I clicked on checksum and get a result like

```
2a803f578f341e164f6753e410413d16ab60fabe31dc491d1fe35c984a5cce696bc71f57757d4538fe7738be04065a216f3ebad4ef7e0ce1bb4c51bc36d6be86
```

and when I click on Signature I will find a result like

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Comment: GPGTools - https://gpgtools.org

iF0EABEKAB0WIQQEKynpKJlbnbljxjbHyhm3tiDXhwUCWyap+AAKCRDHyhm3tiDX
h808AJ40mPQBJN/uKagq3Dkz2A2thpXQpACfR+C1pi3JH403UgRT72UeI3S/nso=
=3apP
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

so I am confused that what should I download and I want to know what is different among those links.
[snap shot of maven download page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMz1y.png)

Comment: I strongly recommend to read https://www.apache.org/dev/release-signing#verifying-signature

Answer (score 2):

The checksum as well as the signature are not maven specific!
The checksum is a sha256 (checksum algorithm) that has been build over the maven binary (Link to .tar.gz etc.). This will be done to allow you to verify that you have downloaded a non manipulated binary!
The same goes for the signature it has been build with [pretty good privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) to allow you to verify an unmanipulated download.

The worse thing is that when someone could do a man in the middle attack for the binary download, then he/she could also do a man in the middle for the checksum and the signature. 
So I would like to suggest to only download maven and forget about the checksum and the signature for beginners.

Comment: Sorry to say that in a harsh way, but your last sentence is simply nonsense. You should always check the checksums of your artifacts or better let Maven it do.You should always configure the checksum policy (See thinks like https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaven%5D+invalid+LOC+header. https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/ ). You should also read https://www.apache.org/dev/release-signing#verifying-signature.

Comment: When we are in the dark old times of modems where we had transmission errors you would be right - but when someone exchanges the file on the server he/she could also exchange the checksum/signature on the server - the same goes for a man in the middle. So the checksum is useless - as long as it is not distributed on a completly different channel! So what would be helpful might be a public register for such signatures - but how to make sure that this will also not manipulated by an attacker?

Comment: You have have not read the links on the download pages very well. The download of the artifact (tar.gz, zip) is offered from mirrors all over the world whereas the checksums and the PGP key are offered only from https://www.apache.org/dist/maven/. Furthermore man in the middle might be done by DNS attack and than Checksums/PGP are really important. BTW: You might think internet is so reliable but I've seem so many issues with that from so many users so I strongly recommend to check the checksums (see my previous comment which are based on transfer issues and others)..

Comment: So when you want to correctly doing this you have to use the signature and if you use it you have to verify that the signature has been created by someone you could trust. So how to do that? As we learned from google/symantec certificate war (I would call it this way) - it's very expensiv to make the whole system safe. Please ask yourself - do you think you could really trust google? I don't think so.

Comment: The gpg keys are all registered https://pgp.mit.edu, Take a deeper look into Apache rules to become committer etc.

Comment: Yes and we have seen manipulated key servers in the past - and spammers got email addresses from the key servers (which opens the doors for social manipulations) ... so this would become a never ending discussion that is indeed off topic to the original question here.So how about posting your own answer to this question?